# Input 0 of layer "max_pooling2d_30" is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=4, found ndim=5

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

I'm just starting to approach ml, and I'm trying to train a model on an image dataset obtained from directories of images using tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory (then pickling it), so that it can predict which letter is fingerspelled in the image.

So, this is how I unpickle my sets of data:

```
#PICKLE LOAD

#TRAIN
  #images
with open('x_train.pkl', 'rb') as x_train_pickle:
  x_train_data = pickle.load(x_train_pickle)
  #labels
with open('y_train.pkl', 'rb') as y_train_pickle:
  y_train_data = pickle.load(y_train_pickle)

#VALIDATION
with open('x_val.pkl', 'rb') as x_val_pickle:
  x_val_data = pickle.load(x_val_pickle)

with open('y_val.pkl', 'rb') as y_val_pickle:
  y_val_data = pickle.load(y_val_pickle)

#TEST
with open('x_test.pkl', 'rb') as x_test_pickle:
  x_test_data = pickle.load(x_test_pickle)

with open('y_test.pkl', 'rb') as y_test_pickle:
  y_test_data = pickle.load(y_test_pickle)
```

Then I convert my array of batches of images to tensor:

```
xTrainTensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(x_train_data)

yTrainTensor =  tf.convert_to_tensor(y_train_data)
```

(same thing for val and test set)

xTrainTensor.shape is (160, 32, 180, 180, 3) -> so I have 160 batches of 32 images, each image being described by width, height and RGBchannel.

yTrainTensor.shape (labels) is (160, 32)

If I print the first batch of labels (yTrainTensor[0]), what I obtain seems actually correct:

[21  3 11  2  7 20  5 12 10  7 14 17 10 17 10  6  9 13 14  2 13 11 15  6
0 11  5  9 15 15 21  2]

-> 32 labels in range 0-21 (I have 22 classes/letters)

Now, the thing is: when I try to model.fit using this architecture:

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
  #tf.keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=(32,180,180,3)),
  tf.keras.layers.Rescaling(1./255),
  tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, 3, activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(),
  tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, 3, activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(),
  tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, 3, activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(),
  tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(len(class_names))
])
model.compile(
  optimizer='adam',
  loss=tf.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
  metrics=['accuracy']
)

epochs = 5
history = model.fit(
  xTrainTensor,
  yTrainTensor,
  validation_data=(x_val_data, y_val_data),
  epochs=epochs
)
```

I get this error:

```
ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer "sequential_12" (type Sequential).

Input 0 of layer "max_pooling2d_30" is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=4, 
found ndim=5. Full shape received: (32, 32, 178, 178, 32)

Call arguments received:
  • inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(32, 32, 180, 180, 3), dtype=float32)
  • training=True
  • mask=None
```

Can anybody please help me understand why this happens? I really can't figure it out, since I believe I have specified the input shape in the first layer...
Thank you in advance and please be kind, I'm just starting!

****UPDATE****

Even though using tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory I obtain an already batched dataset, I reshaped the corresponding tensor so that instead of having shape (160, 32, 180, 180, 3) it has shape (160*32, 180, 180, 3) - using tf.reshape, manually...
And it actually works for me! Hope it makes sense doing it this way, I found no other ways of "unbatching" the dataset created from directory of images...
Thanks everybody for the hints.

Comment: Are the 32 images in a batch related in some way? If not, you should _not_ do the batching beforehand. That is, your data should rather be in the shape `(160*32, 180, 180, 3)`. When providing a tensor to `fit`, the batching will be handled in there (note the `batch_size` argument of that function).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The thing is, I'm using tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory, which automatically creates batches of images... this is the documentation https://tensorflow.google.cn/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/image_dataset_from_directory?hl=ur

Answer (score 0):

You are giving 5D data to Conv2d instead of 4D.So, either your data should be in the shape (batch_size*32, 180, 180, 3)
or
You can use the TimeDistributed layer wrapper to apply the same convolution layer on all the images in the 5D tensor. For example:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.TimeDistributed(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, 3, activation='relu')))

model.summary()
```